# Как при нажатии иконки были незаметны её очертания

Tags: qt

Сделал кнопку QPushButton со свойством flat и вставил в неё иконки(две картинки .png формата). При нажатии надо что бы она зажималась (toggled) , появляется проблема её очертания при нажатии проявляются . Как избавится от очертаний размера кнопки ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в место QPushButton использовать кнопку QToolButton .